# prove two rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ and $J$ be two sided ideals, $I+J=R$. Are $R/I\cap J$ and $I/I\cap J \bigoplus J/I\cap J$ isomorphic?

My guess is yes, because internal and external direct product of two rings are isomorphism. Is my observation right?

Comment: This is trivial.you can prove this as inner direct sum.right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $I/I\cap J, J/I\cap J$ are ideals in $R/I \cap J$ therefore
$$\phi : I/I\cap J \bigoplus J/I\cap J \to R/I \cap J \\
\phi (x+ I \cap J, y+I \cap J)= x+y +I \cap J$$
is well defined, and it is easy to see it is a homeomorphism.

Since $R=I+J$ you get immediately that $\phi$ is onto.

For 1-1, let us check the kernel. If $\phi (x+ I \cap J, y+I \cap J)=0 +I \cap J$ then $x+y \in I \cap J$. Since $x \in I$ you get that $y=(x+y)-x \in I$ and hence $y \in I \cap J$. Same way $x \in I \cap J$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, but I'm not clear on your observation.

Maybe in your observation you meant this: "I see there are two ideals of $R/I\cap J$, namely $I/I\cap J$ and $J/I\cap J$, that have trivial intersection, and add up to $R/I\cap J$, therefore their sum is direct." Not only does that say they are isomorphic, it says the two sets are *equal*.

You could also just apply elementary ring isomorphism theorems.

The Chinese remainder theorem it is isomorphic to $R/I\times R/J$, and the [second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem_2) shows that each of these is isomorphic to what you described.